# Rolling a roulette with chances and counting the maximum same-side sequences of a number of rolls

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate a random sequence of numbers, with each "result" having a chance of {a}48.6%/{b}48.6%/{c}2.8%.

Counting how many times in a sequence of 6 or more {a} occurred, same for {b}.
{c} counts as neutral, meaning that if an {a} sequence is happening, {c} will count as {a}, additionally if a {b} sequence is happening, then {c} will count as {b}.

The thing is that the results seem right, but every "i" iteration seems to give results that are "weighted" either on the {a} side or the {b} side. And I can't seem to figure out why.

I would expect for example to have a result of :
{a:6, b:7, a:8, a:7, b:9} but what I am getting is {a:7, a:9, a:6, a:8} OR {b:7, b:8, b:6} etc.

Any ideas?

```
import sys
import random
from random import seed
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
import time

loopRange = 8
flips = 500

median = 0


for j in range(loopRange):

    random.seed(datetime.now())

    sequenceArray = []

    maxN = 0

    flag1 = -1
    flag2 = -1

    for i in range(flips):

        number = randint(1, 1000)

        if(number <= 486):
            flag1 = 0
            sequenceArray.append(number)

        elif(number > 486 and number <= 972):
            flag1 = 1
            sequenceArray.append(number)

        elif(number > 972):
            sequenceArray.append(number)

        if(flag1 != -1 and flag2 == -1):
            flag2 = flag1

        if(flag1 != flag2):

            sequenceArray.pop()

            if(len(sequenceArray) > maxN):
                maxN = len(sequenceArray)

            if(len(sequenceArray) >= 6):
                print(len(sequenceArray))
                # print(sequenceArray)
            # print(sequenceArray)
            sequenceArray = []

    median += maxN
    print("Maximum sequence is %d " % maxN)
    print("\n")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 1))


median = float(median/loopRange)
print("\n")
print(median)
```

Comment: Do you care about the numbers you used or just the `a`, `b`, `c` classification? The code seems much too baroque. For example, why have two flags instead of just a single variable which tells you the type of the current run?

Comment: I know that the code is a bit poorly written, haven't optimized it yet. The second flag is there because there was a bug. The bug occurred when the FIRST iteration produced a number in the 2.8% chance {c}. When that happened, the flag 2 would never change, and the results would be always 0 for that specific loop. But yeah, i get your point.

Comment: I think you could first of all simplify the code a little bit, it would help in debugging :) For example, `max1`, `max2` and `max3` are only incremented, but have no usage (neither printed or saved). I think you don't need them at all. Also `count` seems to be directly related to `len(sequenceArray)`. You can remove `count` and check the length of the array instead.

Comment: Ye, you are right. I kind of changed the implementation from the first version that i had and didnt mind removing the max variables, good point. 
The problem with the "weighted" generated numbers doesn't make sense to me though.
It probably has something to do with the rand function and the way it gets seeded, that's what i am not getting.

Comment: Your `random` implementation seems okay for me. You can even put the `random.seed` before the two loops, this should not change anything. Indeed `randomint` generates a series of independent draws, even if you don't reset the seed. By default, [Python random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) uses itself the system time to provide a seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement something with two cursors `prev` (previous) and `curr` (current) since you need to detect a change between the current and the previous state.

I just write the code of the inner loop on `i` since the external loop adds complexity without focusing on the source of the problem. You can then include this in your piece of code. It seems to work for me, but I am not sure to understand perfectly how you want to manage all the behaviours (especially at start).

```py
prev = -1
curr = -1
seq = []
maxN = 0

for i in range(flips):
    number = randint(1, 1000)
    if number<=486:
        curr = 0 # case 'a'
    elif number<=972:
        curr = 1 # case 'b'
    else:
        curr = 2 # case 'c', the joker

    if (prev==-1) and (curr==2):
        # If we start with the joker, don't do anything
        # You can add code here to change this behavior
        pass
    else:
        if (prev==-1):
            # At start, it is like the previous element is the current one
            prev=curr
        if (prev==curr) or (curr==2):
            # We continue the sequence
            seq.append(number)
        else:
            # Break the sequence
            maxN = max(maxN,len(seq)) # save maximum length
            if len(seq)>=6:
                print("%u: %r"%(prev,seq))
            seq = [] # reset sequence
            seq.append(number) # don't forget to append the new number! It breaks the sequence, but starts a new one
            prev=curr # We switch case 'a' for 'b', or 'b' for 'a'
```